# Mutiple tables in one query (sum)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am very new in this area and unfortunately my two-day course only learned the basic skills of Access. I found out that I have to write SQL to get what I want, only I am very unexperienced with it so I am currently teaching myself. I know that what I want has something to do with innerjoins of outerjoins, but I can't figure out what I have to do in MY case. p.s. I am Dutch, so my English is probably not the best, but I will try to explain it as best as possible.

**Issue**
I would like to write a query which connects more dan ten tables in one query. These tables consists of products with a specific price, this has to sum up.

Basic table = InstallionID, NameInstallation

Other tables = Compressor, Heating etc. etc.

I would like to present this in one query with a sum of every component for different installations. I managed to get this, but still the amounts are mutiplied in a way. I have to resolve this by doing something with joins, but I can't figure out how.

**Example**
Here I connected three tables, tbl_Installatie, tbl_Besturing and tbl_Elektra

```
SELECT I.INSTALLATIEID, I.NAAMINSTALLATIE,
       Sum(B.PRIJSBESTURING) AS TOTPRIJSBESTURING,
       SUM(PRIJSELEKTRA) AS TOTPRIJSELEKTRA
FROM INSTALLATIE AS I,
     BESTURING AS B,
     ELEKTRA AS E
WHERE I.INSTALLATIEID = B.INSTALLATIEID
  AND I.INSTALLATIEID = E.INSTALLATIEID
GROUP BY I.INSTALLATIEID, I.NAAMINSTALLATIE;
```

Can somebody please help me? I searched in other topics and tried several options, but every time I get an error message.

### Many many thanks in advance!!

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdN7z.png][1]
This is an example of the output of three tables combined. The total price is wrong, because it contains many extra euro's!

Comment: Don't have separate tables for heating, compressors etc, have one common product table!

Comment: Do LEFT JOIN's instead. (Or first UNION ALL the different product tables together.)

Comment: It's difficult to sort out without knowing your table structures. Also, some sample data that exhibits the problem and expected output would be helpful. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for the input! It is an option to combine all the components in one table, but some components have specific characteristics we would like to administrate as well. So compressors have specific brands and capacities then Electra, but maybe it is easier to keep that as side information instead of implementing it all and have all these separate tables.

Answer (score 0):

In sql server use `Outer Apply` for such situations.
[See MS documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)